# Maximum validity for Canadian Multiple entry visas for Nigerians

Tags: visas, canada, visa-expiration

Any Information for maximum visa validity for Canadian tourist multiple entry visas for Nigerian Citizens.

I see something like this [image]

Hence i wanted to know the maximum validity for Visit Visas. I am from Nigeria,

Answer (score 4):

All applicants are automatically considered for a multiple entry visa valid for up to 10 years or one month before their passport expires, whichever is shorter. http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=417&top=16

If what you’re really asking is ‘will I be given a 10 year multiple entry visa?’ the answer is no-one can tell you that with any degree of certainty. It depends on the applicant’s individual circumstances.